# Using functions instead of operators in GLSL / OpenCL?

Tags: function, operators, glsl, opencl, abstraction

Based on my observations on C/C++ compilers, it doesn't make any difference between `a = b + c;` and `assign(a, add(b, c));`

Is it safe to make such substitution in other C-based languages like GLSL, OpenCL and so on? I am building a code generator and I really want to abstract operators away altogether and emulate operators with good old C functions.

Comment: Why do you feel there should be a difference, though? The semantics are identical, scalars and vectors in shading languages are value types so there are no side-effects.

Comment: I don't know how well the dedicated compilers for GLSL and OpenCL handle this kind of operations. How good are they are inlining and so forth. I wouldn't want to do extra function calls for the "operator-function" wrappers for something that can be implemented with single machine instruction. That is my source of concern.

Comment: There are no function calls on GPU's (there is no stack, everything is statically deduced and then inlined - and once this is no longer true, I expect tiny functions like these would be inlined by any sane compiler). So, no, there will be no difference, but you are making the compiler's life harder. If you have a good reason to (e.g. code generator) then it may be worth it, note however that this kind of syntax gets really messy very quickly so I hope no human has to read these later on :p

Comment: It won't be intended for human eyes, the actual code is generated from visual nodes, which is what the programmer interacts with.

Comment: @Thomas - I have a little extra question, considering that an `assign()` function will have to take its target by reference, either as a pointer or reference, but IIRC both of them are unsupported in GLSL, so how would I actually implement such a function so that it assigns to the actual member, not to a copy made  to be passed as a parameter?

Comment: Never mind that, I can use `out` or `inout` to "fake" passing by reference. The valid question is why didn't they just go for "by reference" instead of those extra awkward specifiers...

Comment: It would add needless overhead, having more explicit control with the above mentioned qualifiers is preferred for high-performance languages. You're not really "passing" anything, because there is nothing like a callstack in shaders, you are just telling the compiler that any changes to the input within the function body should be discarded when it eventually inlines everything. Implicitly, this could mean making a copy; if you never change the value of an `in` variable within a function, then no copy is necessary - this has very real performance implications.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it may compile to the same code. To be sure, you'd really have to test it and the only way I know how to do that is currently via [`glShaderBinary`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glShaderBinary.xml) - on nvidia cards it includes some assembly like plaintext in addition to a binary bit (AFAIK there's no docs for this and it's not required by the GL specs).

That said, I would avoid doing this! `inout` doesn't get compiled away as you might expect. Consider this...

```
int global;

void func(inout int arg)
{
    arg = 1;
    global = 2;
}

void main()
{
    func(global);
    //global now equals 1
}
```

According to the specs (good description [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL))), global gets copied *in* to arg, which gets set to 1. global is set to 2, but then the function returns and arg is copied *out*, overriding the 2 with 1.

This operation requires one extra register in this case (actually the compiler probably does further optimizations in this trivial example), but if you're passing a lot of data you can quickly run into *occupancy* issues (see [this](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/177477-slow-local-arrays-in-GLSL)) due to the additional storage requirements of the copy. There's probably some performance overhead too. Copying arrays such as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687208/can-you-pass-a-fixed-size-array-as-a-glsl-function-parameter) can *really* hurt performance.

*[EDIT]*
A safer option might be to use macros for everything...

```
#define add(a, b) ((a)+(b))
#define assign(a, b) (a = b)
```